# Blank page and the console showing me error message about routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The client doesn't show me any problem but all I have is a blank page and an error message in the devtool that says `Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element.`

This means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page." I know is a problem about the routes but I don't know what is it.

```
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            render={(props) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <Hero merchant={merchant} />
                  { this.renderCartNav() }
                  {isCartVisible &&
                    <Cart
                      {...props}
                      cart={cart}
                      onUpdateCartQty={this.handleUpdateCartQty}
                      onRemoveFromCart={this.handleRemoveFromCart}
                      onEmptyCart={this.handleEmptyCart}
                    />
                  }
                  <ProductsList
                    {...props}
                    products={products}
                    onAddToCart={this.handleAddToCart}
                  />
                </>
              );
            }}
          />
          <Route
            path="/checkout"
            exact
            render={(props) => {
              return (
                <Checkout
                  {...props}
                  cart={cart}
                  onCaptureCheckout={this.handleCaptureCheckout}
                />
              )
            }}
          />
          <Route
            path="/confirmation"
            exact
            render={(props) => {
              if (!order) {
                return props.history.push('/');
              }
              return (
                <Confirmation
                  {...props}
                  order={order}
                  onBackToHome={() => window.localStorage.removeItem('order_receipt')}
                />
              )
            }}
          />
        </Routes>
      </>
    );
  }
};
```